# How to access a map in Thymeleaf Spring dialect when the key is changing?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am iterating some data using Thymeleaf's Spring dialect, i.e. using SpEL. The docs describe how to access arrays, lists and maps using numbers or quoted strings:

```
<p th:text="${map['key']}"></p>
<p th:text="${list[0]}"></p>
```

However, the keys/indices here are necessarily constant, and that doesn't help me in this case, because I iterate over multiple keys (that aren't even strings). Two variants I've tried:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="key : ${map}">
//SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 41): Unexpected token. Expected 'rsquare(])' but was 'lcurly({)'
        <p th:text="${otherMap[${key}]}"></p>
//ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type com.example.MyClass
        <p th:text="${otherMap[key]}"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the second one leads me to believe that SpEL tries to use `key` as the String `"key"` here, but then asserts that `otherMap` does not use String keys.

Is there a way to access `otherMap`'s elements?

Answer (score 3):

**Note**

You have to use **double underscore** `__${key}__` to pre-process it and include it in the next level of your processing.

**Solution**

This will solve your issue

```
<li th:each="key : ${map}">
    <p th:text="${otherMap[__${key}__]}"></p>
</li>
```

Given that your controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping("/...")
public String index(Model model) {

    Map<String, String> otherMap = new HashMap<>();
    otherMap.put("one", "1111");
    otherMap.put("two", "2222");
    ....

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    keys.add("one");
    keys.add("two");
    ...

    model.addAttribute("otherMap", otherMap);
    model.addAttribute("map", keys);

    return "<view name>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Not obvious for me, who's coming from Freemarker.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax that worked for me was this (note the `#th:object`):

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="key : ${map}" th:object="${key}">
        <p th:text="${otherMap[#object]}"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

While SpEL tries to parse `${otherMap[*{id}]}` (which is of course different, but I tried it anyway) as a multiplication, it interprets the `#object` notation correctly.

As far as I know, `#object` is Thymeleaf specific, so if there is a similar problem in other use cases of SpEL, this might not work there.